# Не могу найти метод в цепочке прототипов

Tags: javascript

Метод `Number.isInteger()` определяет, является ли переданное значение целым числом.

console.log(Number.prototype);

```
Number {0, constructor: ƒ, toExponential: ƒ, toFixed: ƒ, toPrecision: ƒ, …}
constructor: ƒ Number()
toExponential: ƒ toExponential()
toFixed: ƒ toFixed()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toPrecision: ƒ toPrecision()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Но, где же оно в цепочке прототипов? Уже все пересмотрел, не могу понять)

Comment: А оно не в прототипе. Этот метод находится не у инстанса `Number`. Поэтому его там и нету. Это как статичный (static) метод и принадлжет он функции `Number`.

Comment: В дополнение к комментарию выше хочу добавить, что все методы определенные на Number можно посмотреть так: console.dir(Number)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko понял))) Да, нашел его в методах конструктора) Спасибо большое!)